# Removing middle of sequence of repeated elements

Tags: python, list

I have a script that generates txt files to generate a pwl voltage in cadence for electronic circuit simulation. I need a way of seeing al the times a list contains more than 2 repeated consecutive elements and removing all but 2. I need to do the same modifications on another list, keeping the first and last elements of the sequence.

For example, if I have

```
x_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_list = [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4]
```

and I am using `y_list` as reference for the procedure, the result should be

```
new_x_list = [0, 1, 4, 5]
new_y_list = [0, 2, 2, 4]
```

The (x, y) pairs corresponding to (2, 2) and (3, 2) have been removed from both lists.

I would have started to try stuff but I simply have no idea how to do this task. I don't know how I would, for example, remove by index if the list is changing during the sweep. I also have no idea how to apply the same modifications on the second list.

Comment: You should be able to do this by going through both lists with `zip` while keeping track of what you've seen so far.

Comment: how big is your list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_list = [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4]

n = len(y_list)

prev_number = y_list[0]
i = 1

while (i < (n - 1)):
    current_number = y_list[i]
    next_number = y_list[i + 1]

    if (current_number == prev_number and current_number == next_number):
        y_list.pop(i)
        x_list.pop(i)
        n -= 1 # you decrement n because poping a number shortens the list
    else:
        prev_number = current_number
        i += 1

print(x_list)
print(y_list)
```

Assumes that y_list has at least one item and laso that y_lists length is less then or equal to x_list

Answer (score 0):

An [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) approach. Use `groupby` to group consecutive repeated terms, make a boolean mask and apply it to the original data with `compress`.

```
from itertools import groupby, compress, chain

# data
x = [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
y = [1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8]


# make a y-based mask 
mask = list(chain.from_iterable(
    [True]*n                           # as a list because it will be flattened
    if (n:=len(list(grp))) <= 2
    else [True]+[False]*(n-2)+[True]   # take as representative of the left and right most limit of the group and flag the others
    for _, grp in groupby(y)))



# as generators
xx = compress(x, mask)
yy = compress(y, mask)

# display and consume the generators
print(*xx)
print(*yy)
```

Output

```
1 0 0 1 4 5 3 4 6 7
1 0 0 2 2 4 5 6 6 8
```

---

Remark: the *walrus* operator `:=` is introduced in Python 3.8.

For Python < 3.8 use a custom function such as

```
def grp2mask(grp):
    n = len(list(grp))
    if n <= 2:
        return [True]*n
    return [True]+[False]*(n-2)+[True]
```

to simplify the comprehension

```
mask = list(chain.from_iterable(
    grp2mask(grp)
    for _, grp in groupby(y)))
```